# Fullpage.js - "Loading section" automatic move to "home section" and always getting by url link to "home section"

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

Description

I would like to make first section of my fullPage.js to loaded just first time, as loading animation of a web page. I got this, but every time, when I go to url link of my page it goes to "home section", as my script works:

```
function loadingSlide() {
     setTimeout(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('home');
     }, 2500);
}
```

and I call this function inside afterLoad:

```
afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
     var loadedSection = $(this);

     /* If you are on LOADING (1) slide */
          if (anchorLink == 'loading') {
               loadingSlide();
          }
}
```

how can I achive this, that loading section loads only first time, and then linking by url won't get me to home section every time with animation, and without animation by url link. I want to get to right section and slide with url link.

Link with the "problem": http://dlightjewels.roksamsa.com/

I tried to call this function loadingSlide(), when we are on section 1, but it is not working as I would like to work ...

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Have you tried using the fullpage.js option `animateAnchor:false`?

Comment: I have tried, and it this is not the case. Function loadingSlide() is executing every time, when you get to specific page by url.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like, that getting to specific section or slide by URL, function loadingSlide() always executes, even if you are not on first section (anchorLink == 'loading', or index == 1).

Comment: I would like: When I'm on first section (in my case this is Loading section), I would like to go auto to "home section" and this is it. So always when I come to page it goes to "home section". This already I get, but then, when I go by URL to specific page, it always go to "home section":

Example: When I want to go by URL http://dlightjewels.roksamsa.com/#true-colors/2, it gets to right section and right slide, but after timeout it goes to http://dlightjewels.roksamsa.com/#home.